# a vectorized approach to create a new column in pandas dataframe with a value from another column but not same row

Tags: python-3.x, database, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column from the existing values of a column, based on on a matching condition with Another column. But the value to be filled may or may not from the same row.

I have implemented this with a nested for loop, but on a large dataset it takes a lot of time. So is there some inbuilt functions to exploit the vetorizing properties of pandas?

My dataset looks like this:

```
    a     b
32  m   1.5
33  n   1.6
34  o   1.7
35  m   1.8
36  n   2.2
37  m   2.4
38  n   2.9
39  o   2.1
40  p   1.5
```

If `m` is encountered in column `a`, the value in column `b` is to be copied into the new column until a new instance of `m` is encountered. And the value is updated. So the output should look like this:

```
    a     b     c
32  m   1.5   1.5
33  n   1.6   1.5
34  o   1.7   1.5
35  m   1.8   1.8
36  n   2.2   1.8
37  m   2.4   2.4
38  n   2.9   2.4
39  o   2.1   2.4
40  p   1.5   2.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace non matched values tested by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` with forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].where(df['a'].eq('m')).ffill()
print (df)
    a    b    c
32  m  1.5  1.5
33  n  1.6  1.5
34  o  1.7  1.5
35  m  1.8  1.8
36  n  2.2  1.8
37  m  2.4  2.4
38  n  2.9  2.4
39  o  2.1  2.4
40  p  1.5  2.4
```